# Resizing window without wrapping the divs within

Tags: html, css

I have a JS Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zuer7g75/1/

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".category-navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse category-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>

    <li>
        <a  href="/computers">
            Computers
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>

        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/desktops">
                Desktops
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/notebooks">
                Notebooks
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/software">
                Software
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a  href="/electronics">
            Electronics
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>

        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/camera-photo">
                Camera &amp; photo
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/cell-phones">
                Cell phones
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/others">
                Others
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li>
        <a  href="/apparel">
            Apparel
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>

        </a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
            <a href="/shoes">
                Shoes
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/clothing">
                Clothing
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/accessories">
                Accessories
            </a>
        </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/digital-downloads">
                Digital downloads
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/books">
                Books
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/jewelry">
                Jewelry
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/gift-cards">
                Gift Cards
            </a>
        </li>


            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <form action="/search" method="get" onsubmit="return check_small_search_form()">    <div class="search_box pull-right">
        <input type="text"  id="small-searchterms"  autocomplete="off"
                    value="Search store" name="q"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Search store')this.value=''" onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value = 'Search store';}" />
    </div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.navbar a.dropdown-toggle').on('click', function (e) {
            var elmnt = $(this).parent().parent();
            if (!elmnt.hasClass('nav')) {
                var li = $(this).parent();
                var heightParent = parseInt(elmnt.css('height').replace('px', '')) / 2;
                var widthParent = parseInt(elmnt.css('width').replace('px', '')) - 10;

                if (!li.hasClass('open')) li.addClass('open')
                else li.removeClass('open');
                $(this).next().css('top', heightParent + 'px');
                $(this).next().css('left', widthParent + 'px');

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    function setMouseHoverDropdown() {
        if ($(window).innerWidth() > 767) {
            $('ul.nav li').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('> .dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
            });
        }
    }
    $(window).load(function () {
        setMouseHoverDropdown();
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setMouseHoverDropdown();
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        setMouseHoverDropdown();
    });
</script>

</body>
```

In JS fiddle , by default you will see a mobile menu.

Please expand the result menu of JS fiddle to maximum. now you will see the web view instead of mobile.

It has a menu which says computers electronics etc and you can see a search box on the right hand side.

Now if you try to decrease the width of jsfiddle result window slowly, you can see the search box jumpind down to bottom.

I want the search menu to stay in same line as the menu, instead wrap the contents of menu into two lines..

How do I do that.

Comment: means you want to make search stay first also in mobile menu right.?

Comment: I am happy about the mobile menu.. I want to change only in web menu.. ir big screen

Comment: so where you want to set in web menu.?

Comment: are you looking like this **https://jsfiddle.net/zuer7g75/4/**

Comment: No the search text box should be on top line (ie same as home icon) but the last one (ir gift cards) should wrap to next line while you resize

Comment: http://eshopper.com.rose.arvixe.com/ check this site.. same behaviour

Comment: then i think your structure is not good for this because you need to put the search box out side of the navbar's div